# Node at the end of a linked list issue

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, linked-list, head

I'm supposed to create a node at the end of a linked list, and a function should accept a parameter to the head of the list, and adds 2 existing integers values to the new node (`int age`, `int id`).

My problem is when `listHead` (which is the pointer to the head of the list) keeps saying unidentified.

Here's my function for the new node to be added to the end:

```
int insert(int n, int m)
{
    StudentCard* tempp = new StudentCard;
    tempp->id = n;
    tempp->age = m;
    tempp->next = NULL;
    if (listHead = NULL)
    {
        listHead = tempp;
    }
    else
    {
        StudentCard* tempp2 = listHead;
        while (tempp2->next != NULL)
        {
            tempp2 = tempp->next;
        }
        tempp2->next = tempp;
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=n2CtLNbp is the full code, the function is all the way at the bottom.

Comment: This appears to be C++ (you should tag it as such).

Comment: Please provide the declaration of the list elements as part of the question. Are you using a single-linked-list or double-linked-list? Do you keep only a head pointer, or head and tail pointer? Likely you are not initializing the list head correctly.

Comment: StudentCard *listHead; // pointer to the head of the list
listHead = NULL;
This was declared right after main(), check out my pastebin document

Comment: `listHead` is defined *inside* `main()`, and as such its name can only be found within the scope thereof. Have `insert()` (and your other linked list functions) take a reference to a pointer to `StudentCard*` that will act as the head of the linked list. You also have a problem in the `if` statement of this method where `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparision operator. Do `if (listHead == NULL)` instead.

Comment: StudentCard * insert(StudentCard* l, int n, int m){ is the function now with reference to pointer added, and everywhere that i had listHead in that function is replaced wiht 'l', and fixed the listHead == NULL, no errors anymore, but how can i test that this works? also.. Do i need a return value anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `listHead` in `insert`, however there is no such variable declared in that scope. That's the problem.

Comment: It worked, int insert(StudentCard* listHead, int n, int m){ , but how do i test that it works? and also which return value ?

Comment: You don't need to return a value in `insert`. Just declare it as `void`.

Comment: okay, and how do i print the value of the void ? Also, is there anything wrong with this declaration:  void insert(StudentCard* l, int n, int m){

Comment: why do you need to print its value? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. `insert` should just append a new node at the end of your list, it shouldn't return anything. `void` in this context means "the function doesn't return anything" so it makes no sens to print it.